# JGroups equivalent library in C++

Tags: c++, sdl, jgroups

at work we have been using JGroups and I have to say that I really like it, however, at home I primarily build with C/C++.

I'm wondering if anyone knows of any good/solid ports of JGroups to C++ or any other equivalent software library for C++. I'm interested in hearing pros/cons of various libraries out there.

Though this isn't a requirement, I am most familiar with [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/)'s SDL_net so a nice wrapper class around SDL_net would be the most favorable to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any ports of JGroups to C++. Some folks run JGroups as a daemon and then talk to it from other languages via a protocol. I recently created a STOMP protocol, which allows for messages sent by clients written in different languages to be processed by JGroups, and for those clients to receive messages as well.

Re: native stacks, you could take a look at Spread (www.spread.org).

Comment: I'll check it out. I'm really mainly looking for a C++ version, it doesn't necessarily have to be an exact port, but anything similar.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out 0mq. Its pretty fast and easy to use.